# Chaining multiple scopes that contain joins() and select()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Everything I read advises people to keep "complex" queries out of the controller and put them into scopes on the model. However, how do you recommend doing this with a query that needs data from three models while using `joins`. For example,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :profile
end
```

If we need `companies.name` and `profiles.city` from the `User`, we could stuff the query into the controller action, which works great.

```
User.joins(:company, :profile).select('users.*, companies.name as company_name, profiles.city as city').find(1)
```

To keep this out of the controller, we could define a named scope, for example

```
scope :include_company_name_and_profile_city, -> { joins(:company, :profile).select('users.*, companies.name as company_name, profiles.city as city') }
```

and in the controller use `User.include_company_name_and_profile_city.find(1)`.

But what if at different times we need *just* the company name or *just* the profile city? Can we define two scopes and chain them?

```
scope :include_company_name, -> { joins(:company).select('users.*, companies.name as company_name') }
scope :include_profile_city, -> { joins(:profile).select('users.*, profiles.city as city') }
```

Calling `User.include_company_name.include_profile_city.find(1)` will yield a query that includes two `users.*` in the SELECT clause.

`SELECT users.*, companies.name as company_name, profiles.city as city, users.*, ...`

What is the recommended way of handling this?

1. Put all `joins()` and `select()` calls in the controller?
2. Create one scope that loads common association data and not care about possible overhead if that data isn't ever used? (this is flawed imo, see below)
3. Create multiple named scopes that do not contain the `select('users.*')` and append a `select('users.*')` either in the controller or in a default scope?
4. Does having multiple `users.*` in the select clause even matter?

If people recommend option 2, what about a situation where we need more (not-so-common) association data in some other template? (ie, `User.include_common_association_data.include_non_common_association_data.find(1)`). This will suffer from the same issue mentioned above (multiple `users.*` in the select clause).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the actual question, but it sounds like you are writing joins and selects when ActiveRecord does all of that for you?

Are these your models?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :profile
end
...
class Company 
  has_many :users
end

class Profile
  has_many :users
end
```

So if you are trying to do this:

> If we need companies.name and profiles.city from the User, we could
>   stuff the query into the controller action, which works great.

you could get those by that Active Record relationship:

```
user = User.find(whatever).includes(:company, :profile)
user.company.name 
user.profile.city
```

**edited to show eager loading using includes**
You don't need a scope to figure out either of those attributes unless there is more to this. Scopes are used to basically automatically filter from attributes.

```
scope :latest, order("created_at desc").limit(3)
scope :city_present, where("city is not null")
```

**edit**: if you haven't spent time on it before, the [activerecord query interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) guide is very helpful. 
Also, ActiveRecord is very smart at optimizing your queries without you telling it what to do, if you want to see the SQL it renders use the rails console to see.

Comment: `user = User.find(1)` will execute one query, accessing `user.company.name` will execute a second (`SELECT * FROM companies ...`), `user.profile.city` will execute a third (`SELECT * FROM profiles ...`). You can optimize this, though, with `joins()` and `select()` using `User.joins(:company, :profile).select('users.*, companies.name as company_name, profiles.city as city').find(1)`, which will add a `company_name` and `city` attribute on the user instance while only executing one query.

Comment: Yes, but if you do eager loading of the joined objects, it will do one query for all three and you have the fully loaded objects, instead of just plucking specifics in a select. 

"Active Record lets you eager load any number of associations with a single Model.find call by using an array, hash, or a nested hash of array/hash with the includes method.`"

Comment: Nope. I'm assuming that people write each scope specifically for what data they need, but this introduces duplication which I don't like.

Comment: did you see my point about using includes to query multiple objects at once (in one query)?